# why result "eightnine" comes together when we input is 8 and 11?

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop

When I run my code with the inputs 8 and 11, the output is

```
eightnine
odd
even
odd
```

The result I expect is:

```
eight
nine
odd
even
```

Why does eightnine appear on the same line? Is there a problem with the loop?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
int a, b;

    scanf("%d\n%d", &a, &b);

    char list[11][5]={"one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","even","odd"};
    int i;
    for (i=a;i<=b;i++)
    {
        printf("%s \n",(i<9?list[i-1]:list[9+i%2]));
    }

     return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because here

```
 char list[11][5]
```

You don't have enough space to store all the strings. The biggest word is `5` letters long, but with a null terminator, that's `6` chars that you need for a word. As a result, that null terminator is dropped, and what's left in the memory is `eightnine` without a null terminator inbetween.

Change it to `char list[11][6]` and it'll work.

But do you really need those strings on the stack anyway? You could just have it as `char *list[11]`, then you wouldn't need to hard-code that longest word length.

Comment: It's not undefined behaviour: in C, if the array has no space for the nul terminator when initializing, it is [dropped](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/array_initialization#Initialization_from_strings).

Answer (score 6):

You need `char list[11][6]`, that is you need space for NUL (the 0 that terminates a C-style string) for the 5 character words.

Although that said, I'd prefer

```
char* list[] ={"one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","even","odd"};
```

and all such issues drop away. Let the compiler do the counting!

Answer (score 3):

The format conversion specifier `s` expects an argument that points to the first character of a string and the function `printf` outputs characters of the string until the terminating zero character is encountered.

As you declared the arrys as

```
char list[11][5] = { /* ...*/ };
             ^^^
```

then these string initializers `"three"`, `"seven`", and `"eight"` are stored in the array without their terminating zero.

So the corresponding elements of the array are stored sequentially for example like

```
...{ 'e', 'i', 'g', 'h', 't' }, { 'n', 'i', 'n', 'e', '\0' }, ...
```

So using the format conversion specifier `s` to output the 7-th element of the array you will get `eightnine`.

So you need to enlarge the outermost dimension of the array like

```
char list[11][6] = { /* ...*/ };
             ^^^
```

But in any case it would be better to define the array like a one-dimensional constant array

```
const char * list[] = 
{
    "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "even", "odd"
};
```

I added also the string literal `"zero"`.

In this case there is no need to bother about the second dimension of the array.

Also pay attention to that as the type of the variables `a` and `b` is `int` then the user can input a negative number. In this case the program will have undefined behavior.

So redeclare the variables like

```
unsigned int a, b;
scanf("%u%u", &a, &b);
```

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    const char * list[] =
    {
        "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", 
        "seven", "eight", "nine", "even", "odd" 
    };
    const unsigned int N = 10;

    unsigned int a, b;

    scanf( "%u%u", &a, &b );

    if ( b < a )
    {
        unsigned int tmp = a;
        a = b;
        b = tmp;
    }

    for ( unsigned int i = a; i <= b; i++ )
    {
        printf( "%s\n", i < N ? list[i] : list[N + i % 2] );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

If to enter `0` and `11` then the output will look

```
zero
one
two
three
four
five
six
seven
eight
nine
even
odd
```

Answer (score 1):

regarding:

```
printf("%s \n", (i<9)? list[i-1] : list[9+(i%2)] );
```

and iterating from 8...11 results in:

```
eight 
odd 
even 
odd

index 8 selects "eight" from the list
index 9 is the sum of  9+1 = list[ 10 ] = "odd"
index 10 is the sum of 9+0 = list[ 9  ] = "even"
index 11 is the sum of 9+1 = list[ 10 ] = "odd"
```

Note: for ease of readability and understanding, you should insert a space between parts of the syntax.  Suggest replacing:

```
printf("%s \n",(i<9?list[i-1]:list[9+i%2]));
```

with:

```
printf("%s \n", (i<9)? list[i-1] : list[9+(i%2)] );
```